# How to fetch a translation from a subdocument nested in an array?

Tags: mongodb

With a schema like this, where the "items" field contains an array of subdocuments with nested translations :

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("513740415b51ea0803000001"),
        "items" : [
                {
                        "id" : ObjectId("5137407f5b51ea100f000000"),
                        "title" : {
                                "en" : "Yes",
                                "fr" : "Oui",
                                "es" : "Si"
                        }
                },
                {
                        "id" : ObjectId("5137407f5b51ea100f000003"),
                        "title" : {
                                "en" : "No"
                        }
                }

        ],
}
```

How would you fetch the English ( "en" ) translation from the item "5137407f5b51ea100f000000" ?

The result should return "Yes".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the shell it would be:

```js
db.test.findOne(
    {'items.id': ObjectId("5137407f5b51ea100f000000")}, 
    {'items.$': 1}
).items[0].title.en
```

Comment: Awesome, I didn't know I could append ".items[0].title.en" at the end of the query.

Comment: @JohnnyForgetJr.: Don't forget the return type of the `findOne()`